# Can I reset the initial set price for erc20 token on uniswap?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, exchanges, mining-pools, liquidity-provider

I am relatively new to cryptocurrency and wanted to try listing an erc20 token. I listed my erc20 token on Uniswap and set its initial price while adding the first liquidity. Later, I wanted to change the initial price and removed my liquidity to redo the whole process and change the initial price. However, I could not set the initial price for my token and the unwanted price still remains and I have to add liquidity according to the unwanted price. I have searched for a solution but have failed to find any documentation or suggestion regarding the issue. Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a little liquidity, for example 10$ in both sides, then make a swap and it changes the balance and price of the liquidity, then add liquidity. If you want to decrease the initial price, swap your ERC20 token for the other pair and if you want to increase the initial price, swap other side for ERC20 token (You must set Slippage Tolerance too high)

Comment: Thank you @AhmadGorji !! I will definitely try this. But just out of curiosity, is there no way of setting the initial price without swapping after adding liquidity for the first time?

Comment: To be honest I did not find any